# How to fetch live data from influxDb

Tags: reactjs, influxdb

We store live data in influxDb, I want to get live data from influxdb at certain intervals and show it in React graphics.
For this, I think I need to open a web socket connection to influxDb. But is there such a thing? Can I open a web socket connection directly from the react frontend to influxDb?
How should I transfer time series data from influxDb to react? I want the highchrat charts to refresh every 30 seconds